# How to write unit test case for a function in jest React?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have created a function in my component. I want to know how can I write unit test cases for that function.

component code is -

```
const Test = () => {
   if(props.Test) {
     props.Test();
   }
}
```

my Test code is -

```
const Test =() => {
console.log("hi");
}
```

and then pass this Test function into my component. I am getting code coverage is not done in this function. So how to achieve code coverage for this function ?

I am passing a function named Test in this component. I need to check if I am getting this component in props then execute this function. So how Can I write unit test cases for this function in jest ?

Answer (score 1):

First mock the function, for instance:

`const mockTest = jest.fn()`;

Then pass it as a prop to your component, and test if it was called:

`expect(mockTest).toHaveBeenCalled();`

More on that: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html

Comment: I am not sure what is this `Test` function, are you trying to mock it or use the original?

Comment: I am trying to it original. I have created a Test function in app.tsx file then passing this Test function in another component file.

Comment: Then you can `spy` on the function and then test if has been called.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you explain it ?